# SQL Aggregate to create a dynamic column using the lag function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to generate a running total using two columns where one of the columns id going to be used in the next row as follows

```
X   Y   Z

1  Y1  Z1 = Constant_vales
1  Y2  Z2 = Y1 + Z1
1  Y3  Z3 = Y2 + Z2
1  Y4  Z4 = Y3 + Z3
```

I want the sum be partitioned over (x)

ANY help would be appreciated

Thanks

I tried the following (sample from my actual query) but didn't work as I expected

```
CASE 
WHEN ff.date = '2018-04-30' then ff.BALANCE
ELSE
LAG(ff.BALANCE,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ff.contact ORDER BY ff.date DESC) + 
LAG(ff.[Rental Pymts],1) OVER (PARTITION BY ff.contact ORDER BY ff.date DESC)
END AS [DAILY BALANCE]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a cumulative sum.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered sets*.  You need a column that specifies the ordering:

```
select t.*,
       (first_value(z) over (partition by x order by <ordering col>> +
        sum(y1) over (partition by x order by <ordering col>) -
        y1
       ) as new_z
from t;
```